# Is there a way to get ubuntu to behave more sanely when short of memory

Tags: memory-usage

(sorry I couldn't think of a good way to phrase this question)

If I ran windows and opened 1000 tabs in opera what I would get is opera will report that it's "out of memory" or opera might stop responding but the operating system as a whole will still be responsive and thus tabs could be closed and no reboot needed

If I run linux and opened 1000 tabs in opera, the OS will keep trying to allocate memory for each tab until it reaches a point where the WM becomes unresponsive to any input (other than REISUB).

My question is, is there a way to configure ubuntu to behave more like windows in this respect?